# Replacing ' " ' in a string

Tags: c#, xamarin

Some string variables have a `"` in the data which recks with my php code. I want to take it out in my `C#` code before the data gets passed to php. I just can't remember the way of doing it, but I tried with this :

```
line.Replace(@""", "");
```

This is not correct in Xamarin, what is the good syntax?

Comment: String.Replace(" " ,"");

Comment: @Apoorv that would replace all regular whitespace characters with nothing. OP want's to replace the `"` character in a string.

Comment: i was just giving him the syntax...

Answer (score 3):

I guess this would work.

```
line.replace("\"","");
```

Comment: Thanks ! .. Forgot that.. :)

Answer (score 3):

use `\` to escape it.

```
line.Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: Thanks ! .. Forgot that.. :)

Comment: Happens in busy time :-)